# Windows 11 unstable after 50% + RAM is used

Tags: windows-11

Windows 11 when RAM usage reaches 55-60%, Windows file explore and other apps become unresponsive. But I don't get any warnings on low memory usage. What I do get is apps termination errors.

This occurs on two different hardware configurations. One has 32 GB RAM, the other has 96 GB RAM. Problem is the same on both machines and more likely related to Windows build. (to be confirmed).

They are different in terms of architecture, hardware, software used etc. Only common thing is **Windows 11** with two slightly different versions:

PC 1 - **Version    10.0.22631 Build 22631**

PC 2 - **Version    10.0.22621 Build 22621**

Both machines would become unstable and start crashing when ever RAM usages goes to (MAX) 60%. I can't go above, somethings has to crash to free some RAM or system will hang due to "no available ram".

Would it be related to allocated Shared GPU memory? I know it should be available to system if GPU isn't using it but... My system allocated 40 GB shared memory to GPU, while GPU has 12 GB of it's own memory.

Has anyone else faced similar or same issue?

Comment: You've probably a faulty memory module, or one module isn't correctly installed, or maybe your mainboard has a malfunction.

Comment: Try both memtest and HCI memtest, run it for at least a day, maybe two days on the 96GB machine. Faulty RAM in both machines is unlikely.

Comment: Which programs are using a lot of RAM?

Comment: Thanks all for reply. It depends, workload is different on both machines; running AI tools, 
 Adobe or VS 2022, does not matter which app consumes the most. Machines are very much different but having same issue (strange RAM limit). I have not mentioned I have HyperV and related services enabled on both, but no VMs running (all stopped). It could be that system blindly reserves RAM. Strange one for sure

Comment: Would it be related to allocated Shared GPU memory? I know it should be available to system if GPU isn't using it but... My system allocated 40 GB to GPU, while GPU has 12 GB of it's own memory.